# Somar dinamicamente todos os campos do FormBuilder. Front-end Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

eu tenho 5 campos do formBuilder. os 5 são preenchidos com dados que vem do banco de dados. mas esses dados podem ser alterados pelo usuario

formNum: FormGroup;

```
recebeDados(){
   this.serviceEndpoint.pegarValores().subscribe(res=> {
       this.formulario(res.data);
  });
}

formulario(result: Dados){
    this.formNum = this.fb.group({
      campo1: result.dado1,
      campo2: result.dado2, 
      campo2: result.dado3,
      campo2 :result.dado4,    
      campo2: result.dado5
    });
}
```

preciso formar dinamicamente esse form builder. por exemplo, esses inputs tem seus valores iniciais:

```
input1 => 0.3
input1 => 0.7
input1 => 5
total=> 6
```

mas o usuário foi e alterou um campo:

```
input1 => 1
input1 => 0.7
input1 => 5
```

e o total precisa alterar junto: **total=> 6.7**

alguma ideia?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Beleza é até bem simples, vou tentar passar uma explicação mais ou menos para chegar no resultado final...

Você pode começar fazendo um map reduce nos valores do FormBuilder, vamos melhorar essa explicação:

A classe FormBuilder tem uma propriedade que fornece acesso a classe FormGroup, classe que possui um array com os FormControls e seus respectivos values.

Parece confuso mas o FormBuilder é organizado assim, dentro dele possuímos o FormGroup  esse é responsável por agrupar os FormControls. A classe FormControls é a representação de um campo do formulário, pois nela conseguimos pegar informações sobre o campo.

Então complementando o que eu disse anteriormente, adicione um eventListerner nos campos desse form por exemplo o listerner onChange.

Toda vez que o onChange for disparado, faça o map reduce para obter o total de todos os campos do form.

Após obter o total, use o FormGroup para encontrar o FormControl do campo total.

Pela classe FormControl é possível setar o valor do campo, assim é só setar o valor total.

Claro se o campo total também faz parte do FormGroup na hora do map reduce, você vai precisar ignorar ele dá conta.

---

Se tem duvidas sobre o que é Map Reduce da uma olhada aqui no próprio stackoverflow tem muita coisa legal, você vai aprender que Map Reduce tem haver com programação funcional.

- [Doc FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder)
- [Doc FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)
- [Doc FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl)